# PHP Soap - Could not connect to host

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have looked at other solutions for this but can't find a similar issue:

This bit of code works ok:

```
$wsdlUrl = "https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk/URUws/uru10a.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new soapclient($wsdlUrl);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

However when I try to make a method call:

```
$params = array("AddressLookupUK" => array("address" => array("Postcode" => "NE20 9RF"),
            'AccountName' => "xxxx",
            'Password' => "xxxx"));
$result = $client->AddressLookupUK($params);
```

I get the error message "SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host".  If I change the method call to

```
$result = $client->FalseMethod($params);
```

I get back "Function ("FalseMethod") is not a valid method for this service" which shows it is connecting as expected.  Does anybody have any pointers I can try?

Thanks

Comment: The first thing I would do here is crack out [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) and have a look at the HTTP requests that are being made and the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used, hope it helps someone:

```
$wsdlUrl = "address.wsdl";  


$client = new soapclient($wsdlUrl);
$params = array('address' => array('Postcode' => $postcode, 'BuildingNo' => $buildingNo),
                'AccountName' => 'XXXX',
                'Password' => 'XXXX');              
$result = $client->AddressLookupUK($params);
$echoText = '';
if (is_null($result->AddressLookupUKResult))
{
    //tell the user nothing was returned
}
else
{
    //checks to see if the result set contains only one item
    if (is_array($result->AddressLookupUKResult->URUAddressFixed))
    {
        foreach($result->AddressLookupUKResult->URUAddressFixed as $item)
        {
            //use code like $item->BuildingNo to access the data
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //if there was there was more than one then access using something like
        $result->AddressLookupUKResult->URUAddressFixed->BuildingNo
    }
}
```

Richard

Answer (score 1):

At the WSDL you see the endpoint deinition:

```
<wsdl:service name="URU10a">
    <wsdl:port name="URU10aSoap" binding="tns:URU10aSoap">
        <soap:address location="https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk:8443/URUws/uru10a.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="URU10aSoap12" binding="tns:URU10aSoap12">
        <soap12:address location="https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk:8443/URUws/uru10a.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I think, you have problems connecting the 8443 port. In my restricted network, the service works neither.

**EDIT**

Ok, I tried to connect using the standard SSL port by changing the WSDL. I have saved the WSDL from https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk/URUws/uru10a.asmx?wsdl to my hard drive, removed the port numbers from the endpoint definitions and tried to connect using soapUI. **Hooray, I got a response.**

So maybe they moved the service from 8443 to 443 w/o updating the WSDL. Or it runs under both ports but you (and me) cannot connect the 8443 because of limitations of our local networks. Anyway I think you should contact the provider of this service and clarify this point instead of using a patched version of their WSDL.

Comment: Ah right, the original URL I was supposed to connect to was https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk:8443/URUws/uru10a.asmx?wsdl but when I called the 

    $client = new soapclient("https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk:8443/URUws/uru10a.asmx?wsdl");

I kept getting "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL".  Is there something special I need to do to create a new soap client against a non-standard port number?  

Thanks

Comment: You could try to download the WSDL, remove the port number, save your edited WSDL in your projects folder and just load it from the filesystem: `$client = new soapclient("myOwn.wsdl");`. If the service really runs at the SSL default port, this should work.

Comment: The strange thing is I have soapUI installed on the server and I have no issue making a call and getting a response from the 8443 URL.  As soon as I try to make the soapclient with it in PHP it doesn't like it

Comment: Someone has posted this behavior as a bug right here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30359 Is this you? If it's working with soapUI on 8443 for you, it may be a PHP bug. To be sure, you have to analyze the network flow (see DaveRandom’s comment on Wireshark).

Comment: No that wasn't me.  I'll have a look in to wireshark now.  Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the later posts for the eventual solution.  Thanks again for your help DerVO

Comment: It looks, the problem was a totaly different one. Anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The "Function ("FalseMethod") is not a valid method for this service" error is only due to the WSDL check. PHP successfully downloaded the WSDL, but can't access the Webservices in it.

You have to debug the Soap Call with `trace` set to 1:

```
$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$result = $client->SomeFunction();
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
echo "RESPONSE HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() . "\n";
echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
```

Also, have a look at the URL's sets in the Wsdl.

Comment: Ah right, the original URL I was supposed to connect to was https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk:8443/URUws/uru10a.asmx?wsdl but when I called the 

    $client = new soapclient("https://pilot.prove-uru.co.uk:8443/URUws/uru10a.asmx?wsdl");

I kept getting "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL".  Is there something special I need to do to create a new soap client against a non-standard port number?  

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I accepted DerVO's answer as his pointers helped me resolve the issue.  The port number was not totally causing the issue but I feel may have been contributing to it in some way.

When loading the WSDL in soap UI it was displaying the simple and complex object types without issue, but within PHP this caused it to fall over i.e. the WSDL defined a set of "

Richard